# Can you specify "select unique name from ..." with NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I've got some data stored in Core Data that looks something like:

| name | identifier | other_stuff |

I need to display the names in a UITableView, but I only want to display the names with unique name-identifier pairs.  So for:

```
John | 3 | foo
Betty | 4 | foo
Betty | 4 | bar
```

I only want the query to return John, Betty.  Something like "select unique name, identifier from table."

Any way to do this with NSPredicate, or do I need to pour the de-duped fields into a different container, then search on that?

Answer (score 10):

Core Data is an *object* graph management framework that just happens to (optionally) persist that object graph to a SQL persistent store. There is no way to query object attributes, just objects. You can query the instances then, from the resulting array:

```
NSArray *instances; //from -[NSManagedObject executeFetchRequest:error:]
NSArray *uniqueNames = [instances valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```

assuming the name is in the `name` property.

If what you want is for each user to have one name, one id and multiple {foo,bar,...}, then you should model the situation as a user entity with name and id and a to-many relationship to an entity that represents foo/bar/etc.

You can find more information about the `@distinctUnionOfObjects` (and other collection operators) in the [Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) section of the Key Value Coding Guide.

Answer (score 9):

Since this is Core Data, check out [`-[NSFetchRequest setReturnsDistinctObjects:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-SW26).